# increase TextSize of ExpandbleListView in android

Tags: android

I want to increase i textsize of ExpandableListView xml

```
 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:childDivider="#00000000"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#9c9c9c"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

Comment: Post your code. Especially the part where you call  `setListAdapter()`

Comment: can you tell me how can increase size using xml or programmatically why adapter required in between

Comment: Because you set the xml for your `ListView` items in the adapter. So we need to see what `Adapter` you use to help you

Answer (score 1):

In your expandable list view adapter you will inflate rows in the `getGroupView()` or `getChildView()` methods, in there you will access your TextViews to populate them with your desired Strings.

Simply call `.setTextSize(*float*)`

an example of `getGroupView()` with view holder pattern:

```
public View getGroupView(final int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row, viewGroup, false);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
        holder.name = tvName;
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
holder.name.setText("your desired text value");
holder.name.setTextSize(22.0f);
}
```